# Crash when permission changed manually

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, crash

Flutter app crashes when user manually changing location perimssion from allow to deny. Is this a normal behavior ?, i've tried to change manually the permissions of other popular apps, they all restart and not crash. But my app after changing permission says Lost Connection to Device and thats it

Comment: When you deny permission from application settings system should immediately kill your app process and maybe restart it if it had running foreground services. If you are experiencing any crash do post your exception stack trace because "my app crashes" is not really helpful.

Comment: It happens either if i deny or if i choose allow when in use permission. There is no stack trace, flutter just give me Lost Connection to Device.

Comment: @RazmikGharibyan hi, were you able to fix this? This happens when ever I deny permissions for location or camera in app settings

Comment: @RLShyam unfortunetly no

Comment: I'm having this too. Seems like its only on debug?

Comment: are you using background location services? if not add custom condition in app with app lifecycle like when app is in resume state check permission status and is it permanently denied show pop that you have to allow permission to use this app

Comment: I would suggest using the Try-Catch block and using variables to store the permission status and don't directly use the status before user Input. So it won't crash your app

Comment: Are you dispose any controller or listener?

Comment: can you tell us more about what device you are talking about? and what is the version of the OS? for example is it IOS 8

Comment: When you try to downgrade permissin it always closed app in debug mode however it will run when you permission upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is a normal behavior on debugging mode , once you change app permission from settings it automatically kills the app and you have to re run it in order for the new settings to take effect
for more info you can read this GitHub issue discussion
https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/166